# Is scraping job posts and gathering skills tags illegal?

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data, scraping

I want to scrape a freelancer site (freelancer.com) and gather their public projects skill tags. Is this illegal to do? And is publishing it illegal?

Comment: Hi @maherbenabdesslam. This question does not seem about data science. You should check the terms and conditions of the site you are referring to. Maybe this question is a better bit at https://law.stackexchange.com/, but I am not sure either.